# Why msiexec TARGETDIR doesn't seem to work

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I tried

```
msiexec /i "yarn-1.10.1.msi" TARGETDIR="C:\programs" /qb
```

The software wwas installed, but not into TARGETDIR. Did I miss something?

Comment: I just ran into the same issue on Windows 10 creating a batch installation job. Some installations are installed into `TARGETDIR`, others not. The `INSTALLDIR` solution from the accepted answer didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following command line instead:

```
msiexec.exe /i "yarn-1.10.1.msi" INSTALLDIR="C:\programs" /qb
```

---

- ***Standards Compliance***: Installing underneath `%ProgramFiles%` is always recommended. Creativity in deployment is generally always overrated and usually causes unnecessary problems. However, you could have an SOE setup that requires custom paths?
- ***Path Update***: A per-user path variable is added to a folder that is not created by default (`%SystemDrive%\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin`). It is by design. The application probably creates the folder when run.

---

***Administrative Installation***: `TARGETDIR` is generally used during [administrative installations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564619/what-is-the-purpose-of-administrative-installation-initiated-using-msiexec-a/5751980#5751980) (essentially a file extraction from the MSI) to specify the output directory for extracted files:

```
msiexec.exe /a yarn-1.10.1.msi TARGETDIR=D:\YarnExtractedFiles\
```

---

[***TARGETDIR***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/targetdir): Without over-complicating too much, let me add two links with more information about `TARGETDIR` (this is to try to make the answer helpful also for others - more "general and generic" info - what you might not need, but that you just might want to know):

- [In WiX files, what does Name="SourceDir" refer to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641094/in-wix-files-what-does-name-sourcedir-refer-to)
- [Why does the TARGETDIR directory need a name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398695/why-does-the-targetdir-directory-need-a-name)